# Returning two models from function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I have a function and would like to  return two models like the following:

```
public function getDetails($id)
{
    $instruments = Instruments::join('revisions', 'revisions.id', '=', 'instruments.revisions_id')
        ->orderBy('instruments.name')
        ->first();

    $team = Team::join('instruments', 'teams.instruments_id', '=', 'instruments.id')
        ->orderBy('instruments.name')
        ->get();

    $result = array($instruments, $team);
    return $result;
}
```

Currently, I was trying to pack the into an array as the following, `$result = array($instruments, $team)`. However, is there a better way to return this two models and access them in a new function?

I kindly ask you for an example.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Array packing is standard practice. This is good.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Any suggestions how to access these models then in another function?

Comment: I actually prefer array packing. So I would strongly discourage doing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge them

```
 $mergedResult = $instruments->merge($team);
```

if there is relationship between two models the you get data on same model

```
    $teamWithIncrements = Team::with('increments')->all();
```